# Which part of script makes JSON API return as array of objects in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I implemented JSON API using ListAPIView. I just wonder which part of script makes JSON API to return as array of objects like below.
[image]
Can anyone point out and where should I change if I want to return just object?
**Views.py**

```
class summaryData(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=summarySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk=self.kwargs['pk']
        key=self.kwargs['keyword']

        return summary.objects.filter(html__pk=pk).filter(keyword=key)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class strToJson(serializers.CharField):

    def to_representation(self,value):
        x=JSON.loads(value)
        return x

class summarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project=serializers.CharField(read_only=True,source="html.project")
    version = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="html.version")
    json = strToJson()

    class Meta:
        model=summary
        fields=('project','version','json')
```

Comment: You have an array of objects, how else is it supposed to return it? Also whats wrong with having the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to get a single object, you want to use a [`RetrieveAPIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview) (or a variant). This would correspond to the "summary detail" url (as opposed to the "summary list" url, where `ListAPIView` makes sense). This is what it should roughly look like:

**path-to-your/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^summaries/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SummaryDetail.as_view()),
]
```

**path-to-your/views.py:**

```
class SummaryDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Summary.objects.all()
    serializer_class = summarySerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `generics.ListAPIView` this means your intention is to get list of all objects so `generics.ListAPIView` gives array of objects. check this blog for [ref](http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html)